# Android getting ID from Database on Onitemclick listener

Tags: android, listview

Hi I have searched through various questions related to this but i am unable to resolve the issue.

I am new to Android and i am developing an application for cricket. Here i am displaying a team from database whichcontains TeamId and TeamName.TeamId is a autogenerated Value. when i click on particular team i want to get the selected TeamId from database and i want to pass this TeamID as bundle to handle next function. But i am not getting the Team Id from database.

And below is the code what i am trying so far,

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
    teamName=(ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Teams");
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 

     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,teamName);
    teamList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ListView OnITEMCLICk

```
    teamList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int id,long position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             textOfSelectedItem  =((TextView) v).getText().toString();
             Log.v("Clicked item id", " "+ id); 


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked is " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            oncreated = false;
            Intent intent=new Intent(TeamOneActivity.this,TeamPlayersTeamOne.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected teamname", textOfSelectedItem);
            startActivity(intent);
            ///g.setSelectedTeamOne(textOfSelectedItem);
        }
    });
```

And this is my database

```
    public ArrayList<String> getTeamID() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> TeamList=new ArrayList<String>();         
    String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;       
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);       
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            //String TeamName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TeamName"));
            String TeamID=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TeamID"));
            //TeamList.add(TeamName);
            TeamList.add(TeamID);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());        
        cursor.close();
    }
    return TeamList; 
}
```

Can any one help how to getId from Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I look at your code I see that you are passing to the intent the value of `textOfSelectedItem`, but your variable is filled with the text that you get from the TextView, which is in no way the ID that you need. You should just write a function to extract the teamID from the database based on the teamName (if that's what you want). So you could use a similar function but instead make the query something lile `"SELECT ID FROM"+TABLE_NAME+"WHERE teamName="+nameOfTeam;` And then just pass that result to your new intent.